# ggplot2 facet_wrap geom_text not accepting date values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a small data set, local,  (5 observations) with two types: a and b.
Each observation has a Date field (p.start), a ratio, and a duration.

```
local

  principal    p.start duration allocated.days    ratio
1         P 2015-03-18        1       162.0000 162.0000
2         V 2015-08-28        4        24.0000   6.0000
3         V 2015-09-03        1        89.0000  89.0000
4         V 2015-03-30        1        32.0000  32.0000
5         P 2015-01-29        1       150.1667 150.1667

str(local)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ principal     : chr  "P" "V" "V" "V" ...
 $ p.start       : Date, format: "2015-03-18" "2015-08-28" "2015-09-03" "2015-03-30" ...
 $ duration      : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 4 1 1 1
 $ allocated.days: num  162 24 89 32 150
 $ ratio         : num  162 6 89 32 150
```

I have another data frame, stats, with text to be added to a faceted plot.

```
stats

  principal         xx    yy            zz
1         P 2015-02-28 145.8 Average = 156
2         V 2015-02-28 145.8  Average = 24

str(stats)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ principal: chr  "P" "V"
 $ xx       : Date, format: "2015-02-28" "2015-02-28"
 $ yy       : num  146 146
 $ zz       : chr  "Average = 156" "Average = 24"
```

The following code fails:

```
p     = ggplot (local, aes (x = p.start, y = ratio, size = duration))
p     = p + geom_point (colour = "blue"); p
p     = p + facet_wrap (~ principal, nrow = 2); p
p     = p + geom_text(aes(x=xx, y=yy, label=zz), data= stats)
p
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Any ideas?  I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message. I get "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'duration' not found" instead, which is due to the fact that there is no column `duration` in `stats`. Are you sure that you are running exactly the code you showed? And which version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are plotting from 2 data.frames, but your initial `ggplot` call includes `aes` parameters referring to just the `local` data.frame.

So although your `geom_text` specifies `data=stats`, it is still looking for `size=duration`.

The following line works for me:

```
ggplot(local) +
  geom_point(aes(x=p.start, y=ratio, size=duration), colour="blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ principal, nrow=2) +
  geom_text(data=stats, aes(x=xx, y=yy, label=zz))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `size = duration` from `ggplot (local, aes (x = p.start, y = ratio, size = duration))` and add it into `geom_point (colour = "blue")`. Then, it should work.

```
ggplot(local, aes(x=p.start, y=ratio))+
geom_point(colour="blue", aes(size=duration))+
facet_wrap(~principal, nrow=2)+
geom_text(aes(x=xx, y=yy, label=zz), data=stats)
```

[image]